# Option[Future[Option[Int]]] => Future[Option[Int]]

Tags: scala

Given a `Option[Future[Option[Int]]]`:

```
scala> val x: Option[Future[Option[Int]]] = Some ( Future ( Some ( 10 ) ) )
x: Option[scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Int]]] = 
    Some(scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@446a1e84)
```

I want `Future[Option[Int]]`.

I can pattern match (or use `Option#getOrElse`):

```
scala> x match { 
     |   case Some(f) => f
     |   case None    => Future { None } 
     | }
res6: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Int]] =  
     scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@446a1e84

scala> res6.value
res7: Option[scala.util.Try[Option[Int]]] = Some(Success(Some(10)))
```

But, is there a higher-order function that will do the job?

I thought of using `sequence`, but I don't have an outer type of `List`:

```
> :t sequence
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

Comment: If you're just peeling away the outer layer, why not just use`x.getOrElse( Future {None} )`?

Comment: FYI `Future.successful(None)` is a slight optimization over `Future { None }` in this instance.

Comment: What's `slight optimization` mean? From an idiomatic Scala point-of-view?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Future.successful(value) is just warp value, Future { value } is push instance to execution context

Comment: An Option[Future] can be turned into a completed Future with Option.map(Future.successful).getOrElse(Future.failed(new Exception)) and this can be automated with an implicit class as shown by Rex Kerr at http://stackoverflow.com/questions./14385633/futureoption-in-scala-for-comprehensions

Comment: @TrisNefzger It sounds like Kevin wants an outer `None` to become an inner `None`, not to fail the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haskell's `sequence` isn't as generic as it could be, or as generic as Scalaz's (and I'm assuming you're okay with a Scalaz solution since you mention `sequence`).

Scalaz's `sequence` (and Haskell's `sequenceA` in `Data.Traversable`) only requires that the outer type constructor have a `Traverse` instance—it doesn't necessarily have to be a list. `Option` has a `Traverse` instance, so `sequence` will work just fine here:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def collapse(x: Option[Future[Option[Int]]]): Future[Option[Int]] =
  x.sequence.map(_.flatten)
```

Scalaz also provides an `orZero` extension method for `Option`, which would allow you just to write `x.orZero`, since the zero of `Future[Option[Int]]` is `Future(None)`.

I'd actually probably use `x.getOrElse(Future.successful(None))`, though, in this case—it's slightly (probably irrelevantly) more performant, but more importantly it's as clear and almost as concise as the Scalaz options.